# Error reformatting string conditionally

Tags: python

I had this subsection of my application working yesterday, and I can't seem to find out why it's not working now.

Here's what it should do:

Input: `10th ave 501`

Output: `501 10th ave`

This block of code is supposed to search for one of the target words in a list called `patterns`, and if there is a number with `len <= 4` after it, move it to the front of the string. `patterns` contains words such as `ave, street, road, place`.

Here is my code:

```
address = address.split(' ')
for pattern in patterns:
    try:
        if address[0].isdigit():
            continue
        location = address.index(pattern) + 1
        number_location = address[location]
        if 'th' in address[location + 1] or 'floor' in address[location + 1] or '#' in address[location]:
            continue
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        continue
    if number_location.isdigit() and len(number_location) <= 4:
        address = [number_location] + address[:location] + address[location+1:]
        break
address = ' '.join(address)

print address
```

Currently the output is just the exact same as what I inputted. i.e `10th ave 501` is returning `10th ave 501`. I feel like it's something relatively obvious that i'm glancing over.

Comment: One tip for easier understanding of your code: only put one type of data in a single variable name.  Eg you have `address` as a string and also as a list (`address = address.split(' ')`).

Comment: How is the length of 501 not less than or equal to 4?

Comment: @Harrison If this is not homework and you want to deal with the problem of normalizing streets maybe this [package](https://github.com/openvenues/pypostal) could help you out

Comment: oh nevermind, I always mix up with less than / greater than.

Comment: @BPL This is not homework. And i've looked at address validation/normalizing packages however they can't benefit me. The address quality that i'm getting is so poor that it has to be cleaned/formatted a lot prior to me being able to geocode them (the goal).

Comment: ok, the part that is breaking is `if 'th' in address[location + 1] or 'floor' in address[location + 1]` it raises an `IndexError` because it is trying to access the element from the list **after** the number which there is none, then the except case continues, I assume that is not the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'10th'.isdigit()` is `False` since:

> Return true if **all** characters in the string are digits ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit))

If you wish, you can check only the first character:

```
if number_location[0].isdigit() and len(number_location) <= 4:
```

Comment: Makes sense. This is supposed to handle cases where correct addresses also pass through the application, such as `501 10th ave`. What can I do to handle all cases? By this I mean if an address already starts with a # then it passes through, but anything else will get tested.

Comment: I'm not sure what are all the cases. You need to define yourself all the options and then work it out.